# Calculate dimension of an affine algebraic set

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to calculate the dimension of algebraic sets in affine space using sympy. I doubt sympy has functionality for finding the dimension defined as;

"the maximal length of all ascending chains of proper distinct non-empty sub varieties"

**Is there a built in sympy function to calcuate the krull dimension of a ring?**

I couldn't find one. If there is, I could just use that on the coordinate ring on a given algebraic set to obtain the dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing close to this that I found in SymPy is [`is_zero_dimensional`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.polytools.is_zero_dimensional), which checks if an Ideal generated by a Groebner is zero dimensional.  It's possible that I missed something, though, particularly in [the AGCA module](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/agca.html).